# Integrating things like $\int e^{-a^2x^2/2} e^{-a^2(b-x)^2/2}/(x+i\tau) dx $

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Recently just came along the integral of the following type:
$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-a^2 x^2/2} e^{-a^2 (\delta x-x)^2/2}}{x + i \tau} dx $.
As it contains an explicitly written pole, complex analysis must be used, but the Gaussians "as is" diverge at $x \to \pm i \infty$. What one can do in such situations? Redefine the generalization for complex $x$ by taking $|x|^2$ instead of $x^2$ as the former decays in any direction?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what is the issue with the usage of complex calculus here, but I found out that this is nothing else than a convolution of a Lorenzian, and a Gaussian, which is the Faddeeva function (can be shown through definitions):

$$ - i \pi e^{-\delta x^2 a^2/4} w\left( \frac{\left( \delta x + i 2 \tau \right) a}{2} \right),$$

where $\tau > 0$ is real, and $w(z)$ is the Faddeeva function.