# How to integrate the following $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{t - i \alpha} \dfrac{1}{t + i \beta/2} \dfrac{1}{(\tau - t) - i\alpha} dt$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-integration

Recently encountered an integral of the following kind:
$$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{t - i \alpha} \dfrac{1}{t + i \beta/2} \dfrac{1}{(\tau - t) - i\alpha}  dt ,$$
where $\alpha, \beta, \tau$ are real, $\alpha$ can be either positive or negative in general, but $\beta$ is always positive. In a sense, it is a convolution of a product of the first two terms with the third one. Expanding in a $\dfrac{C_1}{t - i \alpha} + \dfrac{C_2}{t + i \beta/2} + \dfrac{C_3}{(\tau - t) - i\alpha}$ does not help as the system on the constants yields the same product of $3$ fractions.

Any chances to have an analytical answer?

Side remark:
With complex analysis tricks, I am a little bit puzzled... Even though for a given sign of $\alpha$ either the 1st or the 3rd term has a pole in an upper half-plane, and asymptotically the integrand behaves as $~1/k^3$ (so, seems integrable), the numerical answer does not match the analytical one, probably, I am missing something. Is that possible to use complex analysis tricks at all for such integrands?

Comment: Are you looking for the Cauchy principal value?

Comment: Hello, @TheSimpliFire! Not sure I understand you correctly, none of the poles are exactly on the real axis for this integral.

Comment: Complex integration, IMHO, is a shortcut. Close the contour in the upper half-plane , integrating along a big circle of the radius $R$. Let $\alpha, \beta, \tau>0$. Integral along a big circle $\to0$ as $R\to\infty$, and we have one pole in the upper half-plane: $t=i\alpha$ (two other poles lie in the lower half-plane: $t=-i\beta/2;\, t=\tau-i\alpha$).
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{t - i \alpha} \frac{1}{t + i \beta/2} \frac{1}{(\tau - t) - i\alpha} dt=2\pi i\frac{1}{i \alpha + i \beta/2}\frac{1}{(\tau - i\alpha) - i\alpha}=\frac{4\pi}{(2\alpha+\beta)(\tau-2i\alpha)}$$

Comment: Hello, @Svyatoslav! Thank you for your answer, you are right! Seems like when I numerically checked the answer, I made a stupid typo, and was wondering why residue theorem did not work. Consequently, when $\alpha<0$, the other term has a pole in the upper plane. 
So, is it correct to say that sufficient condition is that the function decays faster than $~1/k$ on the infinity in order to say that the upper semicircle contribution is zero?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. $I_R=\int_0^{\pi}g(Re^{i\phi})iRe^{i\phi}d\phi$. Then we look at the asymptotics of $|g(Re^{i\phi})|$ at $R\to\infty$. If $|g(Re^{i\phi})|<\frac{1}{R^s}$ at $R\to\infty$, and $s>1$, then $I_R\to 0$

Comment: By the way, would also appreciate if you could have a look at an older question of mine https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420642/integrating-things-like-int-e-a2x2-2-e-a2b-x2-2-xi-tau-dx